# Unity Firebase Remote Config updating incredibly slow

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I set up a value to use on the firebase console but it takes more than half a day to update. Is that supposed to happen? Here's my code. It always returns successful, but it only gives the previous updated value.

```
case Firebase.RemoteConfig.LastFetchStatus.Success:
    Firebase.RemoteConfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig.ActivateFetched();
    statusText.text = "Remote data loaded and ready.";
    dateText.text =   Firebase.RemoteConfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig.GetValue("eventDate").StringValue;
    DebugLog("Firebase dateText: " + dateText.text);
    EventTimer.Instance.SetRemoteConfigDate(dateText.text);

    DebugLog("Firebase Remote data loaded and ready.");
    break;
```

Comment: It's look like your remote config have been throttled. Here is a tutorial provide some common problems when working with firebase and how to prevent them. Hope it will help. https://killertee.wordpress.com/2020/01/08/make-use-of-firebase-remote-config-in-your-unity-game/

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Remote Config caches values so that your fetches won't spam the service and cause undue network usage on your users' devices.  It will also throttle your fetches if you try to fetch too frequently.

During development (and only during development), use "[development mode](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#remote-config-requests)" and set your fetch cache expiration to 0 so you can test changes to Remote Config parameters.

Answer (score 0):

are you test it in pc unity editor?
you need deploy in android or ios device.

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/9